# How to lookup value of key-value pairs in XML

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my XML response:

```
<FrontendStatus xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                version="1.1" serializerVersion="1.1">
  <Name>jason-P35-DS3</Name>
  <Version>v0.28-pre-3339-g9877c07</Version>
  <State>
    <String>
      <Key>currentlocation</Key><Value>playbackbox</Value>
    </String>
    <String>
      <Key>menutheme</Key><Value>mediacentermenu</Value>
    </String>
    <String>
      <Key>state</Key><Value>idle</Value>
    </String>
  </State>
  <ChapterTimes/>
  <SubtitleTracks/>
  <AudioTracks/>
</FrontendStatus>
```

I am trying to output the value of the key "state" and have the output as just

> idle

The XSLT I currently have is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output  indent="yes" method="text" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>


 <xsl:template match="*">

   <xsl:copy-of select="/*/*[normalize-space(Key)='state']/Value"/>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but my output is just blank.

Comment: Why not simply XPath? Without root element, this will not be a well-formed xml output.

Comment: This is for OpenHAB for home automation and it requires XSLT documents to transform XML responses into useable information

Comment: Consider slight modification of your path: `/*/*/String[Key='state']/Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For your given XML, this XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="//Key[.='state']/following-sibling::Value"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**will output**

```
idle
```

**as requested.**

Comment: Thank you so much, that's nothing like what I had and I spent hours researching it.